# Python Scheduler Clarification

Tags: python, scheduler

```
import schedule
import time
from os import system

def job():
      system(‘file.py')

schedule.every(2).minutes.do(job)   
while True:
      schedule.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)
```

I thought this code is suppose to run the script as if it was manually ran. The point of this code is to run it on intervals and give me output. When I run it keeps giving me a text of the code. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm trying to run scripts without using windows or task scheduler. What I'm I missing.

Comment: The `‘` in `system(‘file.py')` should be `'` or the code won't run.

Comment: That is a typo because the original code has single quotes